# Unpredictable calling order between Received event and BasicConsume

Tags: c#, lambda, rabbitmq

My problem is, that my code is running unpredictable. First here is my code:

```
var receivedmsg = "empty_string";
channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "rabbittestqueue",
                        durable: false,
                        exclusive: false,
                        autoDelete: false,
                        arguments: null);

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    var body = ea.Body;
    String message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received message1: {0}", message); 
    receivedmsg = message;

};
channel.BasicConsume(queue: "rabbittestqueue",
                        noAck: true,
                        consumer: consumer);

Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received message2: {0}", receivedmsg); 
return receivedmsg;
```

The problem is, that **[x] Received message2** run sometimes first, then **[x] Received message1**

The code that I'm using is from here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

Why does this happening?

Comment: C# doesn't have unpredictable calling order, RabbitMQ might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a "push" consumer method to pull messages.

If you want to "pull" messages from the queue, use the "pull API", which is called `BasicGet` instead of `BasicConsume`.

Having a predictable and syncronous "push API" is self-contradictory. The "push" will happen when it happens... not when you want it to happen in your application. That's the point of a "push" API.

You can find a general API description [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html), especially the headings **Fetching Individual Messages ("pull API")** and **Retrieving Messages By Subscription ("push API")**.

Comment: I don't find BasicGet api anywhere. Where should I find it?

Comment: @Twi I added a paragraph.

Comment: Thanks I found there how to use the pull API: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote

```
Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received message2: {0}", receivedmsg);
```

in the "main thread" and

```
Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received message1: {0}", message);
```

in the event that happens when the message is received. The console output order will be like that in 99.99% of the time.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for you to have the line `Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received message2: {0}", receivedmsg)` in the code. The messages are coming from FIFO queue practically always.

Comment: The main problem is, that I want to return the string message somehow.  I can't return any value in the _consumer.Received_ block. I trying to return it after the block, but sometimes I can return it, because the block which get message haven't run yet.

Comment: When you a are using an event based callbacks (maybe a bit redundant statement), you need to take care about stuff like signalling/notifications, waiting on resource etc. What do you expect to be in the `receivedmsg` variable if it has not been initialised, that is message not received? Additionally messages should be processed in the callbacks, I never had or saw an use case where for whatever reason I'd need to put message outside of this.

Comment: I am trying to implement this: Sending a message to a MQ, then I read the message, and compare them. If they identical everyting went ok. So how should I test the message received?

Comment: There are so many ways to do this, but it is completely unnecessary to write and perform such a test.

Comment: What do you suggest to me?